# Http 404 error while downloading .jad file from server onto the mobile

Tags: blackberry

I have completed my application and put it on the server.
But when i m trying to download .jad file then the error `Http 404 error` occurs.
What is the problem with it.
Please give me the instruction to download the file.

Comment: Wrong URL? Have you considered case-sensitivity? Does the filename conatains spaces? Have you tried to open the URL with a browser? Or just with a blackberry?

Comment: I have use right URL.
No i have not considered cose-sensitivity.
File name doesn't cotains spaces.
This is run in leptop's web browser but not work in any mobile.
i have open the URL in iphone,windows mobile,blackberry and android all returns same 404 error.

Comment: check the url. its working in internet explorer ?. if yes, then there is no problem. else, the url is not pointing the correct file. check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .jad and the .cod's should be in the same directory, and if you're in a apache server need the .htacess file like this.

```
AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor .jad

AddType application/vnd.rim.cod .cod
```

You should point your URL to the .jad file and let it do the work.